# Адекватно показать html на форме

Tags: c#, html, winforms, vb.net, webbrowser

На что можно заменить контрол WebBrowser (или что с ним сделать) чтобы:

- поддерживался адекватный уровень css (ну уж точно не IE7)
- программу можно было запустить на любом компьютере без установки компонентов (админских прав не будет).
- никакие манипуляции с разметкой не требуются - просто отобразить страницу.

Смотрел на WebKit.Net - его демопример не умеет открывать локальные файлы, и на awesomium - там настораживает необходимость установки sdk - вероятно, надо будет настроить копирование каких-то библиотек к exe'шнику?

Answer (score 1):

Со стандартным WebBrowser решить данную задачу в данных условиях непросто, так как требуются соответствующие изменения в системном реестре (подробнее [на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control) и [тут](http://digitorum.ru/blog/2014/08/04/C-WebBrowser-Emulation.phtml)). Либо права администратора, либо элевация (примеры можно посмотреть, в частности, [тут](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197/administration-elevation) (насколько они рабочие не знаю, не проверял))

> awesomium - там настораживает необходимость установки sdk - вероятно,
>   надо будет настроить копирование каких-то библиотек к exe'шнику?

Практически любой SDK требует наличия своих сборок. [Как подключить сторонний браузер в приложении на C#](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170015/).

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы завтра оно сразу заработало на компьютере, где админских прав у меня нет. Поэтому и спросил. А статью видел. Пока решил обойтись возможностями IE7, на случай, если ничего лучше не получится сделать.