# Как заставить стандартный браузер .NET притвориться хромом?

Tags: c#, webbrowser, chromium

Открываю определённый сайт, а он не хочет работать со стандартным браузером.
Как сделать, что бы он заголовки отправлял другие и притворялся хромом?

Comment: Если не пугает изменение в реестре, то можно отображать с более поздним IE из установленных - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control

Comment: ссылка по теме - [Web Browser Control & Specifying the IE Version](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version)

Comment: Если не секрет, можно узнать что это за сайт?

Comment: @"Foggy Finder" не секрет- курсы валют- ru.tradingview.com и api там нужного мне нет. Только топорным методом выдирать данные надо

Comment: а что именно вам нужно достать? может вам вообще `webbrowser` не нужен или нужно отображение страницы тоже?

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Он IE и работает соответствующим образом. Более того, он IE7 и большинство современных сайтов со скриптами в нём всё равно не заработают.

Посылай запросы сам через `HttpWebRequest` и сам управляй заголовками.

Чтобы притвориться хормом надо задать соответствующий `user-agent`, например:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36` и не забыть, что надо сохранять и обрабатывать куки. Вот [тут](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6758025#p6758025) можно посмотреть пример.

Другой вариант - вместо стандартного браузера использовать что-то хромиумное. Есть несколько контролов, но когда я пытался их [по-быстрому присобачить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482891/178988) к своему приложению, что-то мне там не понравилось.

Ну и третий вариант - взять нормальный хром и использовать селениум, либо какую-либо обёртку над chrome headless.